# Exclude term of current post in the list of terms of taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress

Under single-CPT.php, I have a `select` tag which displays terms of my taxonomy. I first return the term of the current post then return the other terms. The problem is that I have a redundant current post term even I perfrom an `if` test before displaying the other terms, the if test excludes the term of the current post. What is wrong in my code below? your help is valuable.

```
<select class="select"> 
 <?php 

    $my_current_term =  wp_get_object_terms(get_the_ID(), 'product_category');
    foreach($my_current_term as $c_term)
    {
    ?>


    <option value="<?php echo $c_term->name;?>">
    <?php echo $c_term->name; ?>
    </option>
    <?php

     }
     
    $all_my_terms =  get_terms('product_category');//add asc and order by  name in asc
    
    
    
    foreach ($all_my_terms as $term1 ) {
        if ( $my_current_term->name != $term1->name ) {

        $option = '<option value="'.$term1->name.'">';
        $option .= $term1->name;
        $option .= '</option>';
        echo $option;
        }
    }

     ?>

</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude terms while getting them:

`$all_my_terms =  get_terms( 'product_category', array( 'exclude' => $c_term->term_id ) );`

Also, when using `wp_get_object_terms`, make sure you get an array of term IDs by setting the `fields` argument to `ids`:

`wp_get_object_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_category', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );`